# Worksheet function trouble

Tags: excel, vba

I have a version of this that works but this version dosen't

```
Public Const GlobalSheetName As String = "Sammanställning,Pris_Schrack,Pris_Pelco,Pris_Swansson,Pris_Övrig" 

Sub Tabortblad()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim ShName As String
 Dim SnNumm As Long
 char = Split(GlobalSheetName, ",")
 SnNumm = UBound(char) - LBound(char) + 1
    If Worksheets.Count = SnNumm Then    'bör ändra denna till större antal
       MsgBox "Där finns bara " & SnNumm & " blad"
    Else
       strCancel = MsgBox("Är du säker på att du vill radera bladen", vbOKCancel, "Radera Blad")
           If strCancel = "1" Then
              Application.ScreenUpdating = False
               Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                   For Each char In Split(GlobalSheetName, ",")
                        If Not ws.Name = char Then
                           ws.Activate
                           Worksheets(ws.Name).Delete
                        End If
                   Next
                Next
                 Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("B:B").Value = ""
                 Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("P68:R" & Sheets("Sammanställning").Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = ""
                 Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            End If
       Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       Worksheets("Sammanställning").Activate
       Range("A1").Select
     End If
End Sub
```

Now this is the version that works

```
Sub Tabortblad()
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim ShName As String
 If Worksheets.Count = "5" Then    'bör ändra denna till större antal
    MsgBox "Där finns bara 5 blad"
 Else
    strCancel = MsgBox("Är du säker på att du vill radera bladen", vbOKCancel, "Radera Blad")
    If strCancel = "1" Then
       Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
         For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
          If Not ws.Name = "Sammanställning" Then
          If Not ws.Name = "Pris_Schrack" Then
          If Not ws.Name = "Pris_Pelco" Then
          If Not ws.Name = "Pris_Swansson" Then
          If Not ws.Name = "Pris_Övrig" Then
            ws.Activate
               Worksheets(ws.Name).Delete
          End If
          End If
          End If
          End If
          End If
         Next
          Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("B:B").Value = ""
          Sheets("Sammanställning").Range("P68:R" & Sheets("Sammanställning").Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row + 1).Value = ""
         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     End If
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   Worksheets("Sammanställning").Activate
   Range("A1").Select
  End If
End Sub
```

The problem is `ws.Name` it returns a fault in the first version and in the second it works fine.

I use this to delete the proper worksheets that I added in another sub.
I'm using the constant to collect the sheet names so if I have to add one it's easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could consider deleting in one shot:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim names As String
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If InStr(GlobalSheetName, ws.Name) = 0 Then names = names & ws.Name & "|"
Next
If names <> "" Then Worksheets(Split(Left(names, Len(names) - 1), "|")).Delete
```

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that the first subroutine worked and then confirmed that I was unable to get the second, "not working" subroutine to work.  Then, I was able to get the second subroutine to run completely through by adding the following:

```
option Explicit
Dim strCancel As String, char As Variant
```

First, you should always include "option explicit" at the top of your modules since it forces you to properly define your variables. This was the source of the problem since the `char` variable was not defined and some of the lines of your code expected an array, so it failed at that point. At least, that's what happened for me before I changed `char` to a Variant. You may not want to use a variant for `char`, and I suggest research into the lines of your code using this variable.

I can't help further because I'm not entirely clear what the goal of your code is and I don't understand the non-English words used. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: I started with this and used it for my other sub's that i have in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Run through the worksheets as their count backwards.

```
dim w as long
For w=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count to 1 step-1
  If iserror(application.match(Worksheets(w).Name, array("Sammanställning", "Pris_Schrack", "Pris_Pelco", "Pris_Swansson", "Pris_Övrig"), 0)) Then
       Worksheets(w).Delete
  End If
Next w
```

Be careful the the VBE does not mess up letters like `ä` or `Ö` by converting them to `?`. The VBE doesn't handle unicode.

Comment: I tried this and the VBE got confused on the unicode part as you sad.